# How can I make my view show a 0 when the value of the property behind is 0 to start with?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this viewModel:

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    int points1;

    public int Points1
    {
        get { return points1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != points1)
            {
                points1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Points1");
            }
        }
    }
```

When the application starts the value of points1 is set to 0 here:

```
card.Points1 = App.correctAnswerPerPhrase; // returns a 0
```

When I look on my screen I see nothing and then debugging I see it's because the setter is checking to see if value (0) is not equal to the default value of points1 (0);

So how can I make it so a 0 appears on the screen when the value is 0 at the start ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, your code should still work; as during load the value retrieved will be 0 only. But, if you still want to be able to notify on set value; you can use nullable int as type.

```
int? points1 = null;

public int? Points1
{
    get { return points1; }
    set
    {
        if (value != points1)
        {
            points1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Points1");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

If type of property on target control is string (for e.g. `Entry`.`Text`); then you will need to convert value to string. You can either do that by creating a [converter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Converter/), or a wrapper property.

```
int points1;

public int Points1
{
    get { return points1; }
    set
    {
        if (value != points1)
        {
            points1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Points1");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Points1Str");
        }
    }
}

// bind this property to control
public string Points1Str
{
    get { return points1.ToString(); }
    set {
        int parsedValue = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out parsedValue))
            points1 = parsedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The target is a label so would I still need to convert to a string?

Comment: Don't think so. With label (or bindable property with mode as OneWay) shouldn't need a converter.